# How to add label fontsize bigger script at data's datasets ? [Chartjs]

Tags: chart.js

Chartjs label fontsize code integration.

I'm newbie of Chartjs. I finally could display
couple of chartjs. And I'm trying to adjust label font size bigger.

I read chartjs official manual and I had been trying to add size code into it. but I couldn't change fonts bigger or chart become won't appear.

This is my current code. And its works fine except fontsize.

I would like to know the labels on TOP and when user mouce over onc of data chart indicate a label which I would like to bigger too.
Could someone teach me where to put size code please?

```
 <script>
        const data = {    
            labels: [    
                'React',
                'Flutter',
                'Laravel',
                'IOT',
                'rust',
            ],
            datasets: [{
                data: [
                    {{$react_c}},
                    {{$flutter_c}},
                    {{$laravel_c}},
                    {{$iot_c}},
                    {{$rust_c}},
                ],
                backgroundColor: [    
                    'rgb(2, 30, 20)',    
                    'rgb(89, 50, 230)',    
                    'rgb(134, 50, 230)',    
                    'rgb(179, 50, 230)',  
                    'rgb(255, 25, 136)',
                ],    
                hoverOffset: 4    
            }]    
        };    
        const config = {
            type: 'doughnut',  
            data: data,
        };
        const myChart = new Chart(
            document.getElementById('myChart'),
            config
        );
    </script>
```